# set UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator) coordinates property on Google earth api

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin, utm

I'm want to create a kml with UTM coord when I set a new placemark. This is my code but I don't know where I have to set this property

```
//part of the code
counter++;
placemark= makePlacemark(hitTestResult.getLatitude(), hitTestResult.getLongitude(),
          hitTestResult.getAltitude(), ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE, 'T');
//set placemark name
placemark.setName("PLM" + counter);
//set the placemark on the map
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

var output = placemark.getKml();
alert(output);

function makePlacemark(lat, lng, alt, altMode, iconStr) {
        var icon = ge.createIcon('');
        icon.setHref('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/' + iconStr + '.png');

        var style = ge.createStyle('');
        style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
        style.getIconStyle().getHotSpot().set(0.5, ge.UNITS_FRACTION, 0,ge.UNITS_FRACTION);

        var pt = ge.createPoint('');
        pt.set(lat, lng, alt, altMode, false, false);
        var pm = ge.createPlacemark('PLM' + counter);
        pm.setGeometry(pt);
        pm.setStyleSelector(style);

        return pm;
}
```

---

> You will need to transform (reproject) your coordinates from your UTM
>   projection to epsg:4326

Does it means that Google Earth application uses additional transformations to show the coordinates in UTM? Used it Tools->Options

Comment: Note that GE will display these coordinates whether or not you have loaded any of your own KML.  This view option is unrelated to KML and/or whether you've loaded any of your own data.

Answer (score 2):

The KML spec specifies latitude and longitude on the WGS84 datum.  Arbitrary projections are not supported.

You will need to transform (reproject) your coordinates from your UTM projection to [epsg:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) and then enter the latitude and longitude appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The best server-side coordinate transformation I've found is here:

http://www.jstott.me.uk/phpcoord/

I've used this for years in conjunction with my Google map and GE plugin code.

Anyone know a javascript equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

as stated in earlier posts you will need to convert your UTM coordinates to long lats

a good tool for this client side is:
http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js

see example:
http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/UserGuide

as also stated in an earlier post :
destination coordinates epsg:4326 , the example has them as the source

source for proj4 will be your utms.

with proj4js, and UTM zone 10 north,  http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32610/ :

```
var dest= new Proj4js.Proj(‘EPSG:4236’);     
var Source= new Proj4js.Proj(‘EPSG:32610’);     

// transforming utm ngcoordinates
var p = new Proj4js.Point(489399,5456814);   

Proj4js.transform(source, dest, p);     

var lng= p.x ;
var lat= p.y;
```